# EVENT_DEFINE_ADDRESS_LINES not pushing response back to Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, plugins, addresses

I have a plugin to reorder the address lines in Commerce. Basically to move the Phone Number to the bottom as it drives all my clients nuts.

While the final array, `addressLines` is the correct array and all looks ok it does not seem to be passing `$addressLines` back into getAddressLines function in */src/models/Address.php* Am I missing the obvious here or is there a bug?

```
Event::on(
            Address::class,
            Address::EVENT_DEFINE_ADDRESS_LINES,
            function(DefineAddressLinesEvent $event) {
                // @var array $addressLines
                $addressLines = $event->addressLines;
                // Modify default address lines array
                $addressLinesNewOrder = [
                    'attention',
                    'name',
                    'fullName',
                    'address1',
                    'address2',
                    'address3',
                    'city',
                    'zipCode',
                    'stateText',
                    'countryText',
                    'phone',
                    'alternativePhone',
                    'label',
                    'notes',
                    'businessName',
                    'businessTaxId',
                    'custom1',
                    'custom2',
                    'custom3' ,
                    'custom4',
            ];
            uksort($addressLines, function($x, $y) use ($addressLinesNewOrder) {
                return array_search($x, $addressLinesNewOrder) > array_search($y, $addressLinesNewOrder);
          });

        return $addressLines;

    });
```

https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/addresses.html#address-lines
https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/events.html#defineaddresslines

Comment: Added Github issue here https://github.com/craftcms/commerce/issues/2104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have return $addressLines; when it should be `$event->addressLines = $addressLines;`. In an event the idea is to manipulate the event variables, these will then be used by the code later on. My full event code would look like:

```
Event::on(Address::class, Address::EVENT_DEFINE_ADDRESS_LINES, function(DefineAddressLinesEvent $event) {
    // @var array $addressLines
    $addressLines = $event->addressLines;
    // Modify default address lines array
    $addressLinesNewOrder = [
        'attention',
        'name',
        'fullName',
        'address1',
        'address2',
        'address3',
        'city',
        'zipCode',
        'stateText',
        'countryText',
        'phone',
        'alternativePhone',
        'label',
        'notes',
        'businessName',
        'businessTaxId',
        'custom1',
        'custom2',
        'custom3',
        'custom4',
    ];
    uksort($addressLines, function($x, $y) use ($addressLinesNewOrder) {
        return array_search($x, $addressLinesNewOrder) > array_search($y, $addressLinesNewOrder);
    });

    $event->addressLines = $addressLines;
});
```